# Sorting Array Values with underscore first

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array of values (keys are not important):

`$Array = array("File01","File02","File00","_File03");`

I want to sort this by value, to match my Windows file system, e.g.:

```
Array ( [3] => _File03 [2] => File00 [0] => File01 [1] => File02  )
```

I have tried `asort($Array)`, but this gives me:

```
Array ( [2] => File00 [0] => File01 [1] => File02 [3] => _File03 )
```

Is it possible to sort with **underscores first**?

Comment: try `ksort` function

Comment: `usort` with a little custom comparison function.

Comment: If you seek, you will find. A simple google search provided the answer that I Dup'd with

Comment: @RiggsFolly I saw this earlier, but didn't apply the logic. Thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 2):

try this.. its working.

```
<?php
$array = array("File01","File02","File00","_File03");
function sortUnderscoreToFront($a, $b) {
    if (substr($a, 0, 1) == '_' || substr($b, 0, 1) == '_') {
        return ((substr($a,0,1)=='_')?-1:1);
    }
    return strcmp(strval($a), strval($b));
}
usort($array, 'sortUnderscoreToFront');


echo "<pre>";
print_r($array)."</pre>";
?>
```